# Live search not working on appended input field with jquery

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I am trying to put live search on appended input field, that will append when click action perform on Add More Field Button
This is my Jquery Code

```
var max_fields = 100; //Maximum allowed input fields 
var wrapper    = $(".wrapper"); //Input fields wrapper
var add_button = $(".add_fields"); //Add button class or ID
var x = 1;
$(add_button).click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    if(x < max_fields){ 
        x++; //input field increment and below is the input field form
        $(wrapper).append('<div><div class="row"><div class="col-sm-3"><input id="search" class="form-control" type="text" name="product[]" placeholder="Input Text Here" required /><div id="display"></div></div><a href="javascript:void(0);" class="remove_field">Remove</a></div></div>');
    }
});
$(wrapper).on("click",".remove_field", function(e){ 
    e.preventDefault();$(this).parent('div').remove(); x--; //input field decrement
})
```

This is my searching function

```
$("#search").keyup(function() {
   //Assigning search box value to javascript variable named as "name".
   var name = $('#search').val();
   //Validating, if "name" is empty.
   if (name == "") {
       //Assigning empty value to "display" div in "search.php" file.
       $("#display").html("");
   }
   //If name is not empty.
   else {
       //AJAX is called.
       $.ajax({
           //AJAX type is "Post".
           type: "POST",
           //Data will be sent to "ajax.php".
           url: "auto_fetch_product.php",
           //Data, that will be sent to "ajax.php".
           data: {
               //Assigning value of "name" into "search" variable.
               search: name
           },
           //If result found, this funtion will be called.
           success: function(html) {
               //Assigning result to "display" div in "search.php" file.
               $("#display").html(html).show();
           }
       });
   }});
```

In This i want to perform searching on every added input field.
Is this possible to perform searching on particular added field through Ajax.

**What i tried**
Searching function perfectly working on other input field which is not appended.

Comment: use only `$("#display").html(html);`

Comment: @KUMAR Thank you for answering but this is not working for me

Answer (score 0):

if it is an HTML Response please use HTML function

$("#display").html(html);

if its only returns search result directly assigned to that id

$('#search').val(html);